# How to abort a while loop by clicking a button using C#

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, break

I have a function that displays numbers using a while loop but I want to stop execution of a while loop at random variable value using c# by clicking a button.

For Example:

```
private void FrqSent()
{
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= 5)       
    {  
        i = i + 1;
    }  
}
```

Comment: then it would be better to look at threads as your while loop will hang your UI

Comment: Is this loop running asynchronously or on another thread? if not it is unlikely your button will be doing much

Comment: Use a BackgroundWorker if you are not familiar with the use of multiple threads. Put your funcitionality into the DoWork event of the BackgroundWorker and use RunWorkerAsync() to start the execution of that functionality and CancelAsync() to stop the execution of that functionality.

Comment: Are you doing anything UI related in your while loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a quick example on how you can use a Backgroundworker to accomplish your task:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int i = 1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FrqSent()
    {           
        while (i <= 500000000)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        FrqSent();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
    }
}
```

Just create a new Windows-Forms Project and add a backgroundworker object aswell as 2 buttons. You have to set the DoWork, RunWorkerCompleted and Click events manually.

Edit: Do not forget to set the BackgroundWorker`s WorkerSupportsCancellation property to true.

Answer (score 1):

not very elegant but simple

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool _stop;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _stop = false;
        FrqSent();
    }

    private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _stop = true;
    }

    private void FrqSent()
    {
        int i = 1;
        while (i <= 5000000 && !_stop)
        {
            i = i + 1;
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `Application.DoEvents()` is not just *non-elegant*, it's *ugly*: what if user *close* the form while `FrqSent()` running?